# How to trigger function when specific element is in view, and also it must be triggered only once

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make a counter on website, that is locacted in bottom of web page when i used

```
$(document).on('scroll',function(){
 if ($(window).scrollTop()>1200){
$('.counting').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function(now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        })
    })
}
})
```

but it causes triggering code on every scroll after scroll value exceeds 1200

Comment: Use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) :)

Comment: how could i do that using jquery only?

Comment: jQuery and IntersectionObservers are both JavaScript.

Comment: i was not aware of that .. thanks :) i will check and reply

Comment: Also, can you tell us a bit about your goal? Do you want the counter to start when it is scrolled into view?

Comment: Have you tried: `$(document).off('scroll');` ? (inside the `>1200`)  Or just have a flag outside checks if it's run once already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Viewport Checker`](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker) jQuery plugin to verify if an element is inside the viewport. It will give you the possibility to setup a callback function that can be useful to achieve your scope.

Comment: if i want to run that only once then?

Comment: @FrazAbbas There is an option to run just once the code when the target element is in the viewport. Read the doc about, in particular the callback function part.